# If someone recites an aayah of sujud repeatedly for memorization, how many times does he/she make the sujud

Tags: quran-recitation, sujud

Assalaamualaikum.

I am trying to memorize the Qur'an in sha Allaah. Some surah's have aayah of sujood. So, if I repeatedly recite that soorah many times for memorization, how many times do I have to make the sujood? As many times as I recited, or is just one enough.

Please give references to your answers.

JazaakAllaahu khair

Comment: Once is sufficient in fact I believe I've quoted this in answer somewhere on the site.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamualaikum,
Hope that this will help you:
[Should the prostration of recitation be repeated if the verse of prostration is repeated for the purpose of memorisation?](https://islamqa.info/en/171666)